# App is accessible through Unity Launcher but can't access through terminal

Tags: unity, command-line, bash, launcher, sublime-text

I had installed Sublime Text 3 a few months back, and using some online resource I had made it accessible through Unity Launcher(unfortunately, I don't remember which resource, or how I did it).

So, currently I can only open Sublime Text using launcher and to open a new file I have to use the menu(or Control+N).

I want to be able to open a file in sublime text using terminal.i.e something like:`sublime_text newfile.txt`.

Steps I took:

1.....

I searched and found that SublimeText folder(and the script) was in `/opt` directory.So I wrote a 2 line script to point to the script and run it, and then wrote an an alias called Sublime_Text to run that script and put it in the .bashrc file.

So now I can write `Sublime_Text` and it opens the sublime_text3 editor, but command like `Sublime_Text newfile.txt` does not give me a new file(only opens sublime_text and no newfile)

2.....

I tried to copy the sublime_text script originally in the /opt/sublime_text folder into /usr/bin/ directory (since vim, vi and other terminal commands are kept in that folder). Unfortunately,`sublime_text newfile.txt` shows several errors like:

`Error loading colour scheme Packages/Color Scheme - Default/All Hallow's Eve.tmTheme: Unable to open Packages/Color Scheme - Default/All Hallow's Eve.tmTheme`

and other 3 errors of the form:
`Error loading syntax file"XYZ"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch Sublime Text 3 using `subl` or `subl file` in the terminal.

Comment: didn't know subl is actually sublime_text.question seems too stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

The two simplest ways are going to be:

1. add the directory containing the application to your `PATH` environment variable. For example, add a line like

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/opt/sublime_text
   ```

   to your ~/.bashrc file. You will need to log out and back in for the change to take effect, or *re-source* the file in your current shell e.g.

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. create a *symbolic link* from the executable file to somewhere that's already on your `PATH` e.g.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/sublime_text
   ```

You will need to remove the copy of the script that you placed in `/usr/bin` so that the system doesn't find it first.